# Do ioctl Functions Use 32 bit Pointers?

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

According to the O'Reilly Linux Device Drivers book, the ioctl related callback function (used on the kernel module side) which is part of the file_operations struct is defined as:

```
int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

with the last argument being a pointer.  Since it's an unsigned long does that mean that ioctl communications use 32 bit pointers?  How does this not cause issues when compiled as a 64 bit kernel module?

Comment: `unsigned long` isn't universally 32 bits.  AFAIK, on all 64-bit Linux systems, `unsigned long` is 64 bits.

Comment: Thanks.  I do most of my development on Windows were a long is 32 bits.  Didn't realise on Linux it's 64 bits.

Comment: The last argument isn't always a pointer. Depending on the ioctl command, it might be an integer. The handler might need to convert from `unsigned long` to the integer type that the command is expected to use (particularly if the ioctl command expects a possibly negative `int` value).